# Numpy list of 1D Arrays to 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large list files that contain 2D numpy arrays pickled through `numpy.save`.  I am trying to read the first column of each file and create a new 2D array.

I currently read each column using `numpy.load` with a `mmap`.  The 1D arrays are now in a list.

```
col_list = []
for f in file_list:
    Temp = np.load(f,mmap_mode='r')
    col_list.append(Temp[:,0])
```

How can I convert this into a 2D array?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use

```
numpy.stack(arrays, axis=0)
```

if you have an array of arrays. You can specify the axis in case you want to stack columns and not rows.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, or at least ranked higher. The regular way (with nd.array) doesn't work with lists of ndarrays

Answer (score 28):

The array may be recreated:

```
a = np.array(a.tolist())
```

Comment: This answer needn't be downvoted, it works in instances when @senshin 's answer won't work.

Comment: This answer is only useful when you have an array of arrays, which is not a list of arrays.

Answer (score 24):

You can just call `np.array` on the list of 1D arrays.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arrs = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9])]
>>> arrs
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
>>> arr2d = np.array(arrs)
>>> arr2d.shape
(3, 3)
>>> arr2d
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks this works great.  Since I wanted columns instead of rows I did have to do some transposes and optimize the direction of the data collection, but it works great.

Comment: THis does not work for multidimensional array. Any solution to that?

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for lists of ndarrays. For a cleaner solution see the answer below using np.stack