# Unnesting Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas Series holding one numpy array per entry (same length for all entries) and I would like to convert this to a 2D numpy array. I believe I have read that Series and DataFrames don't behave well when they hold containers, but long story short, this is unfortunately what you get from calling `np.histogram(.,.)[0]` on each group in a series, which is what I am after (a distribution of histograms).

Either way, I would like to retrieve a 2D numpy array from my series. Currently if I do `my_series.values()` I get this:

```
array([array([0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]),
       array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), ..., array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]),
       array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])], dtype=object)
```

The solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322564/numpy-list-of-1d-arrays-to-2d-array) didn't work here (`np.array` didn't *automatically* resolve the final data structure into a 2D array).

How can I "flatten" this 2D array from this data structure? (note: `result.flatten()` doesn't do the trick, nor does `np.array(result)`, both return the original structure)

Comment: All the subarrays have the same shape?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.vstack` to stack a list/array/whatever of rows:

```
>>> A = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
>>> A[0] = array([0, 0, 0])
>>> A[1] = array([1, 2, 3])
>>> A
array([array([0, 0, 0]), array([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
>>> np.vstack(A)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Amazingly, @behzad.nouri's deleted solution is faster than mine for a length-2000 array of `np.arange(10)`'s in NumPy 1.8.2. Behzad, if you undelete I'll upvote. (My solution wins if the inner arrays are larger, though.)

Comment: undeleted, but i think `np.vstack` is cleaner

Answer (score 3):

possibly:

```
>>> xs
array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
>>> xs.shape
(2,)
>>> np.array(xs.tolist())  # or, np.asarray(xs.tolist())
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.array(xs.tolist()).shape
(2, 3)
```